# Force culture-insensitive date fomatting globally in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

We're fetching culture info from the request headers and setting globally in our HTTP request pipeline. This results in DateTime being formatted differently, due to different cultures, when no specific format is specified.

It's possible to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when formatting, but i'd rather not have to remember doing that every time, since our frontend expects the same format every time.

Is there any way to set default global formatting with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: Set `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` at some suitable point during startup? FxCop also has a rule which moans if you forget to pass a `CultureInfo` to a method which accepts one

Comment: @canton7 We are setting those values from the request header. These values need to be set according to user culture, but the dates should not listen to that culture

Comment: Right, so you *just* want to affect how dates are formatted, and not how other numbers are formatted?

Comment: @canton7 Correct. Actually we are only using CultureInfo to fetch correct language from our database. We don't care about the numbers, but dates need to be formatted in the same way.

Comment: Remember that `CurrentUICulture` should be used for language, and `CurrentCulture` for formatting dates/numbers

Comment: Depending on your scenario, [globalization invariant mode](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/globalization-invariant-mode.md) may be useful. Do note that this has way more impact than just fixing date formats, though.

Comment: @canton7 That's a very good point. So I could only set CurrentUICulture and always set the same culture for CurrentCulture, then the dates/numbers would be unaffected?

Comment: That's the idea yes. That's why there's a split between `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: @canton7 Awesome! You saved the day. Thanks.

Comment: @canton7 If you write an answer I'll gladly accept it.